# How can I get CURRENT USERNAME in membership asp.net 2008

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-membership

I use a membership in asp.net 2008. And I build a login system with some rolls ...etc

I have a database and tables and the KEY is "username", and now I want to know how can I get a username for the member who logged in ?

for example:
I logged in as TURKI
I want to get the username TURKI

really I need for help...

thanks,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
User.Identity.Name
```

User is a property of the page. If you need to access it elsewhere, you can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Thanks, I try 
User.Identity.Name

and it's OK!

really thanks!

Comment: Both of the above work fine in a intranet environment when browsing to the page from my local PC - BUT - neither seems to work when logged into our Windows 2003 Terminal Server.

Comment: @John what do u mean with an intranet environment? as u are talking about a difference in behavior, I will take a guess and assume u are not talking about using the sql membership provider, but instead are using integrated authentication. In that case first thing I would check is if that server allows anonymous user. If not, pls post more details, if its long u might want to post a separate question - drop me a link here in that case (although is prob that someone else will answer it before I check again ...)

Answer (score 4):

A modification to Freddy's answer when using MVC - had to use:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

Slight change but figured I would post it in case anyone else trying to do this in MVC hits the same snag.

Answer (score 3):

Context.User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Membership.GetUser() method described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser.aspx

also, if you do get the MembershipUser you could also get the 'ProviderUserKey' which uniquely identifies a user, possibly using that as your FK for your tables, that way your user can have their username updated without having to change all the keys in your tables.

Comment: Yes, but if the username is the only thing needed, you can avoid a round trip to the DB by using the other answers in this thread.