# BEST PRACTICES: Storing Custom Profile Data?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

So this is a bit of a continuation of my previous question.... Reluctantly, I have elected to use the built in ASP.NET/VB authentication. But my main issue now is how to customize it?

For example

1) I need for the username to be an email address, and the build-in version asks for/stores both.

2) What is the best way to store other profile data. {IE address, phone number, etc}.

My ideas...

1) Hide(somehow) the username file on the login control, and pass the email address to both (username & email address) columns.

2) I was going to create a separate table to store the additional data (phone, address, etc) and just keep it by the UserID generated in the ASP Authentication process. But, since I am pretty new at this, I am not sure if there are unseen consequences for doing it this way. In theory it seems that it would work.

The info out there on authentication/membership system is VERY cluttered for someone very new at this. I basically have my site build, but this part. I can't help but to wonder how in the world isn't this easier...

Can anyone offer any input? - Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean ASP.NET membership ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx )? There's a good article at http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx although I do not know what, if anything, has changed from the ASP.NET version that series of articles talks about to the version you are using. There is a built-in mechanism for storing other profile data.

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET membership is what i am talking about. I have it working in a "play" solution. I have added extra customization from the profile properties (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taab950e(v=vs.80).aspx) but i'm not sure how they work. They sound like they are just session based and not stored in the DB, but IDK. ... I will look at the 4guys link and see what I can decipher, hopefully a bit more of an understanding...

Comment: The profile properties are indeed stored in the database and persisted. You can look in the tables that are created for the membership provider to see how they are stored by using SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio.

Comment: actually i just read that on your link, and I also read that the other way I though is a good way. They just don't explain how to pull the UserID (PK) from the cookie that ASP.NET Membership class saves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737839/how-can-i-get-current-username-in-membership-asp-net-2008 looks like what you need.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - VERY close, but in my situation the KEY is the "UserID" (with a datatype of 'uniqueidentifier') column of the aspnet_Membership table. Which is a giant number. I suppose if all else fails I could use the name (which comes up for me as an email address) it just harder to control duplicates that way.

Comment: Got it!! 


`Dim userinfo As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()

        If User.Identity.Name <> Nothing Then
            Dim Guid As Guid = userinfo.ProviderUserKey
        End If`

Comment: You can write your own SQL to query the database for the UserID from the name. Also, the "giant number" you refer to is a GUID.