# Finding the identity of someone logged on a website through WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a website running with ASP.Net membership database, and it's working fine. I also have a WCF service running which is supposed to act as an API for applications implemented onto the website (in my case games). Now my problem is that I want my applications to be able to call the WCF and return the user currently logged onto the website through my database solution, and I can't find a way to do this for the life of me. I've tried using:

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```

But this seems to not have a value (null) when it's called by a session logged in on the website. I want my WCF to be able to update things like highscores etc. based upon who is logged in while running the applications, and this is kinda impossible as far as I know if I can't grab the identity of the person who is logged in. This is how I tried to test this out:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    APIHostClient client = new APIHostClient();
    client.Open();
    String name = client.GetUserName();
    Label.Text = name;
    client.Close();
}

// on the wcf side 
public String GetUserName()
    {
        String userName = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
        return userName;
    }
```

web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAPIHost" >
          <security mode ="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://localhost:2105/APIHost.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAPIHost" contract="ServiceReference1.IAPIHost"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IAPIHost" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="behavior" name="ICanHasGamez.APIHost">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ICanHasGamez.IAPIHost">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService.SecurityValidator, WcfService"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

All information I seem to find on the subject is related to standard authentication of users where you provide the credentials, while my issue is finding the credentials of someone logged onto my website.

### EDIT:

I was looking at the problem from the wrong angle. This is how I am trying to fix it currently: I am generating a SessionId when the user visits a page holding an application, which holds information about the application ID, the user ID visiting the page, and the expiration date of the session (current date + time). You can apparantly forward information directly to .swf files you host (i.e: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html), so I pass the sessionId of the user to the application, which the application dev can then use to access the name of the user in the database by passing the sessionId to a SQL query which returns the acquainted user ID (could make it return the name as well, but the ID is more useful in my case). I will update with an answer if I make this solution work.

Comment: Why you want to find it from wcf? Do you want to pass it to wcf? or just looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737839/how-can-i-get-current-username-in-membership-asp-net-2008

Comment: @YK1 In my case it's a website that will host games. So I want the developer to grab information about who is logged in to the website, to update things like highscore lists etc. on the database. The games are coded separately from the website, so I'm creating an API for them to call on with WCF. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @YK1 yes I basically want the functionality of `User.Identity.Name` , but from the WCF (where you can't call upon this directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My edit solution worked out. Pass the sessionId to the flashfile as a FlashVars and the flash program will have access to the unique sessionId string. From this it's easy to get access to all kinds of information through SQL queries. I had to write the asp.net code that holds the flash object in a script to be able to manipulate the parameter, as the same .aspx page would be used to hold different applications (querystring) with different users connecting.

hfSessionId = a hidden field which has been set to the value of the SessionId in code behind.

```
      <script lang="javascript">

            function writeObjectTag() {

                var sessionId = document.getElementById('<%=hfSessionId.ClientID%>').value;

                document.writeln('<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="myFlashGame" align="middle">');
                document.writeln('<param name="movie" value="sessionIdDisplayer.swf" />');
                document.writeln(buildParamTag(sessionId));
                document.writeln('<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="sessionIdDisplayer.swf" width="550" height="400">');
                document.writeln('<param name="movie" value="sessionIdDisplayer.swf" />');
                document.writeln(buildParamTag(sessionId));
                document.writeln('<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">');
                document.writeln('<img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />');
                document.writeln('</a>');
                document.writeln('</object>');
                document.writeln('</object>');
            }

            function buildParamTag(value) {
                return '<param name="FlashVars" value="' + value + '" />';
            }

      </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**If your web service is going to be called from the browser** (as in a jQuery AJAX call) then you just need to host the WCF service side by side with the ASP.Net application and enable the ASP.Net compatibility mode in the WCF service. It is described in this [article in the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)

I can see that your have already enabled the asp.net compatibility mode in the web.config, by adding

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
     multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

to the element `<service.serviceModel>` of the web.config.

You should also set the `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements]` attribute to your service implementation as in:

```
namespace ICanHasGamez
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class APIHost: IAPIHost
    {
        ...
```

That allows access to `HttpContext.Current` so you can now get the user name as in:

```
public String GetUserName()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

**However, if you want to call the WCF service from the server side code of your .Net web applications** then you also need a way to impersonate the logged in user in the client browser when calling the service. Wiktor´s answer provided a way of doing this, by sending the authentication cookie received in the ASP.Net web application to the WCF service.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input.

I actually had it set to "Allowed" instead of "Required". I changed it, and it still doesn't allow me to call HttpContext, though. The closest thing I can call is `BasicHttpContextBinding` and `WSHttpContextBinding`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn´t allow me", what errors do you get? Is it a compile error? Have you added the namespace `System.Web` in the service implementation? PS. I used required as it seems you will need the user name in the service implementation, but it should work with `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed` as well.

Comment: There is also an example using the ASP.Net compatibility mode and WCF [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx)

Comment: System.Web wasn't added, this fixed being able to call HTTPContext, thanks. I tried to run it and now it tells me that "The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.", though. I'll try fixing this and come back with results.

Comment: Just saw your comment on Wiktor´s answer. It really depends on who will call your WCF service. Will it be the browser or your server side of the ASP.Net application? In the first case, enabling the compatibility mode is enough. In the second case you need to follow Wiktor's answer, impersonating the user logged to your website

Comment: Basically it's an application that is on the server (which will be running in the browsers - think a game uploaded on kongregate.com) which will use the WCF as an API to extract/insert information. At this point, though, I'm just trying to make it so that my browser can call it.

Regarding the previous error it was related to the security I added to my binding when I tried something earlier. I removed it and now it's complaining about the metadata not being available.. trying to fix it now.

Comment: Ok I've fixed it. The httpcontext.current.user.name returns a blank value, though. As you can see I'm trying to set a label to the username in my code, and it's just set to a blank value when this code runs (it has a default value so I'd see if it didn't work at all).

Comment: Then you are calling the WCF service from your server side, in the Page_Load of your test page. So you need to follow Wiktor´s answer to impersonate the legged user in the browser, sending the authentication cookie to the WCF service

Comment: I see. And I presume the same will hold true if applications on the server (which are displayed on the webpage) try to access the WCF service? Thanks for the help, have some rep.

Comment: Yes, as long as you call it from the server side code (the .net code of your web applications) you will need to follow that approach.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work like this easily.

What you try to do is to try to call your WCF from the server. This means that the server has to somehow IMPERSONATE the request, to pass the identity of the caller to the called WCF request.

There are at least few ways to do it.

An easiest approach would be to copy the authentication cookie from the request (it is accessible via the Request.Cookies) to the wcf client. I've blogged on how to do this

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2011/11/managing-cookies-in-wcf-client.html

This has the advantage of reusing the same authentication scheme in both the website and the wcf (which is Forms Authentication) so your wcf is secured for both internal and external requests.

Edit: since you are having problems with it, this is how to do it:

```
APIHostClient client = new APIHostClient();
client.SetCookie( FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, this.Reuqest.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value );
client.Open();
```

(assuming that `SetCokie` is implemented at the WCF side as described in the blog entry)

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks for the input. I will check out that link and see if it helps and come back with the results (I'll still check answers and comments as I do).

Comment: If I understood those articles correctly, If I only have one WCF service, I can just leave allowCookies on true and start processing cookies right away? I.e. `<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAPIHost" allowCookies="true" />`?

When I try to set `client.CookieContainer = nameofcontainer;`, though, it tells me my service contains no definition or extension for CookieContainer, though.

Comment: I assume this is because APIHost doesn't have a method called "CookieContainer", but from how I understood the article it should be an inherent method to wcfservices?

Comment: The Cookie Container property is NOT available for wcf proxies nowadays. It was a part of the old API. Read further to learn how to workaround it.

Comment: I see, thanks, but is the other part of my question correct? With only one WCFService on my site I can leave allowCookies="true"? The article says " the cookie is only handled in the conversation with one web service.", but I'm just wondering if I interpreted this correctly (not a native speaker, sorry). It seems the additional code in your article is mainly for appending new cookies to the service when calling it, if I understood correctly, which I don't need (I only need to be able to read existing cookies - in this case  a cookie which holds the username of the user). cont.

Comment: I have set up this code on the service side to read the cookie I made (I've checked that it's made and stored on the computer, which it is):

        `public String GetUserName()
        {
            String userName;
            HttpCookie sessionInfoCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserInfo"];
            if (sessionInfoCookie != null)
            {
                userName = sessionInfoCookie["UserName"];
                return userName;
            }
            return "No user logged on";
        }`

However it returns "no user logged on" even when the cookie exists.

Comment: You NEED to set up a cookie. Which means that you need to read the cookie from the request and set it up (copy) to the wcf client.

Comment: I see, but my original situation is that another application (in my case a game on the site) needs to be able to find out what the username of a logged on person is. The end-product would need to be able to present the username of the person logged on and return it to the person doing the request. I'm assuming flash games etc. can't directly access cookies, which is why I'm setting up this service in the first place.

Or is the state of the service independent of who is accessing it? So if a webpage sends a cookie to the service, will it be stored there so a later request can access it?

Comment: Edited my answer to give you more clues.

Comment: I.e. can I set it up so that when a user visits a page holding a game, it will append the cookie to the service, and then the game running there will be able to access the cookie in the service, although it wasn't the game that appended it?

Comment: The game, regardless on how it was implemented, can use the same approach - cookies - to access the WCF. Cookies are just http headers, can be handled by ANY client-side technology. Appending Forms cookies to client-side calls is easy.

Comment: Thank you for your patience for "stupid questions". Do you mean that an application (say in flash) is be able to access cookies that are stored locally on the computer running it? So I could just supply the name/structure of the cookie in the API documentation, and the game dev would be able to access the information in it in his own code? If so then it seems a method for extracting information out of cookies on the WCF-side is completely unnecessary for my site.

Comment: No. The application can ASK for a login/password, go to unprotected wcf method and the wcf issues a cookie and returns it to the client.

Comment: So the WCF needs to create the cookie, append it (issue it?) and return it? I see, but that brings me back to the original problem unless I misunderstood your explanation. The information I want to be stored inside the cookie is the username of the person logged in - and the WCF service doesn't have access to this information. I see in your example that you are sending this information with the service request (the setCookie parameters), but the application doesn't have access to this information either, right (which is why I need this service to begin with)? I'm kinda confused.

Comment: The website HAS this information as users are already logged in. At the server side you can just COPY it to access wcf. My previous comment about "application" was meant to clarify the scenario regaring an external application (a mobile one perhaps).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30659/discussion-between-user1339253-and-wiktor-zychla)

Comment: I just can't see how what you are describing is a solution to how to access a stored cookie, but rather how to set up a new one (I'm probably just dumb). I will try to find a solution and update this question with it if I manage to do it. Thank you for your time, but I don't think we are talking about the same problem here.