# Is it possible to access windows username from outside domain?

Tags: c#, iis

I have a website deployed on a server with it's own domain. Is it possible to get the Windows username when that website is launched?

Say i have a website on foobar.com, when i access the site from any random windows desktop, i want to retrieve the windows username from client side.

I use this in code to access the username:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

But this brings up a login prompt for the server that the website is residing, which doesn't help me. Even if i did log on to that server, it is still not getting the current user's windows username.

I have searched almost every post relating to this, but none are specific in this scenario.

IIS is setup to only windows auth. Any info on this is appreciated.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737839/how-can-i-get-current-username-in-membership-asp-net-2008

Comment: I have tried that. I think it's assumed that the server and the user are on the same domain in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally come to the conclusion that this is not possible. Instead went with integrating with Azure AD.